# Scala Try and Either Weird Behavior

Tags: scala, monads, either

So I am playing with the `M` types in Scala and came up with the following regarding `Try` and `Either`:

```
def brokers(throw1: () => List[Int], throw2: List[Int] => List[String]) = {
  println("brokers ===> " +
    (Try(throw1())
      .toEither
      .filterOrElse(!_.isEmpty, Nil)
      .flatMap(xs => Try(throw2(xs)).toEither) match {
        case Right(s) => s
        case Left(f) => throw f.asInstanceOf[Throwable]
      })
    )
}
```

And some test runs:

```
brokers(() => List(1, 2, 3), (xs: List[Int]) => xs.map(_.toString))
brokers(() => Nil, (xs: List[Int]) => throw new RuntimeException("throw2"))
brokers(() => Nil, (xs: List[Int]) => xs.map(_.toString))
brokers(() => throw new RuntimeException("throw1"), (xs: List[Int]) => xs.map(_.toString))
brokers(() => List(1, 2, 3), (xs: List[Int]) => throw new RuntimeException("throw2"))
```

But:

1. `throw f` wouldn't compile: "Expression of type Serializable doesn't conform to expected type Throwable". Thus the cast.
2. Exception from sample run 2:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.immutable.Nil$ cannot
>   be cast to java.lang.Throwable    at
>   Practice$.brokers(Practice.scala:57)  at
>   Practice$.delayedEndpoint$Practice$1(Practice.scala:63)

Why, Scala, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question, turns out `Either.filterOrElse` is not really what I thought it to be. If the predicate doesn't match, `filterOrElse` actually converts `Either[A, B]` to `Either[AA, B]` where `AA` is the "zero" element provided to `filterOrElse`. In my case, it converted the `Either[Throwable,List[Int]] = Right(List())` to a `Either[java.io.Serializable,List[Int]] = Left(List())`. Thus the compile error, and the match with `case Left` and eventual exception. The `Serializable` must have come from the contravariant type parameter `AA >: A`, because guess what, the first common supertype for `Throwable` and `List` is a `Serializable`.

I've filed [SI-10044](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-10044) for this; will see what they say.